# Same application with different assemblies - Singleton not working as expected

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, singleton

I have a complex Winforms application that I have to refactor. I have a big problem with a Singleton-Class that is used in this application. It doesn't do what I think it should do (only in Release-Build).

I have a Program.cs (Proj1.proj) that is the main entry point.

```
    static class Program
    {
        private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));

        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
              XmlConfigurator.Configure();
              log.Debug("Logging enabled");
              File.WriteAllText("test1.txt", "Test");
              DBConnection.Instance.GetConnectionString();
              log.Debug("GetConnectionString called");
              DBConnection.Instance.GetDatabasename();
              log.Debug("GetDatabasename called");
              Application.Run(new Mainform());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
             //...
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the DBConnection.cs (Proj2.proj)

```
public class DBConnection
{
    private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(DBConnection));

    private static DBConnection instance;

    private string connectionString;
    private string databaseName;

    private DBConnection()
    {
        log.Debug("DBConnection ctor");
        this.connectionString = "example";
        this.databaseName = "example2";
    }

    public static DBConnection Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                log.Debug("Instance was null");
                File.WriteAllText("test2.txt", "Instance was null");
                instance = new DBConnection();
            }
            log.Debug("Return instance");
            return instance;
        }
    }

    public string GetConnectionString()
    {
        return this.connectionString;
    }

    public string GetDatabasename()
    {
        return this.databaseName;
    }
}
```

I observed the following in my Winform Application in the Release Build:

- The Log-Entry "Instance was null" is **never** written in the
  log-file
- "Return instance" is written and that suggests that "Instance was null" should be in the log-file
- The Log-Entry "DBConnection ctor" is written more than once
- File.WriteAllText doesn't work (*doesn't create file or write to it / no exception*) in DBConnection.cs but is working in Programm.cs

In Debug Build

- All expected Log-Entries are written and only one Instance is created

What can cause this behaviour? Why does it work in Debug but not in Release? Why does he call the constructor twice? Why are some log-entries not written despite the fact that logging is working. Why does File.WriteAllText not work?

I'm out of ideas and I can't find the cause of the problem. Clearly there has to be a setting in the project somewhere that can cause this... because if you rebuild the example shown above in a new project it will work...

Comment: Concurrency. Implement singleton correctly and problem will be gone. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

Comment: Your singleton is not thread-safe. What is happening: it gets instantiated once before GUI thread gets created, then, probably, once again. http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Comment: @Arie Why would that happen? From the code shown, there's nowhere that `Instance` is called before `Main()` is executed. (It is definitely not threadsafe, though)

Comment: What happens if you replace the Log.Debug() calls with Trace.WriteLine() and then run [DebugView](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/debugview.aspx) to catch the messages as you run the program? I think the problem here is in code you haven't shown us...